# Replicate F# map join in python

Tags: python, pandas, f#

Given map a and map b below, the expected result is val c in F#. I am trying to replicate this behavior in python.

```
let join (p:Map<'a,'b>) (q:Map<'a,'b>) = 
    Map(Seq.concat [ (Map.toSeq p) ; (Map.toSeq q) ])
example:

let a = Map([1,11;2,21;3,31;])

let b = Map([3,32; 4,41;5,51;6,61;])

let c = join a b
and the result:

val c : Map<int,int> =
  map [(1, 11); (2, 21); (3, 32); (4, 41); (5, 51); (6, 61)]
```

Here is what I have attempted in python thus far:

```
df_c = pd.concat([df_a,df_b], join='inner')
```

where df_a and df_b have two columns containing data that matches variable a and variable b in the F# code.
Ultimately, I am unable to replicate the behavior. Instead I get all the results in df_c that are in df_a and df_b. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: kindly share `df_a`, `df_b`, and your expected output `df_c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be the best solution for huge dataframes.

### Creating dataframes

```
>>> df_a = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3], "col2":[11,21,31]})

>>> df_a
   col1  col2
0     1    11
1     2    21
2     3    31

>>> df_b = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [3,4,5,6], "col2":[32,41,51,61]})

>>> df_b
   col1  col2
0     3    32
1     4    41
2     5    51
3     6    61
```

### Concatenate data

```
>>> result_dict = dict(df_a.to_dict('split')['data'])

>>> result_dict
{1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 31}

>>> result_dict.update(dict(df_b.to_dict('split')['data']))
>>> result_dict
{1: 11, 2: 21, 3: 32, 4: 41, 5: 51, 6: 61}
```

### Create result dataframe

```
>>> df_result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict.items())

>>> df_result
   0   1
0  1  11
1  2  21
2  3  32
3  4  41
4  5  51
5  6  61
>>>
```

You can rename the columns if you want/need.

```
>>> df_result.rename(columns={0: "col1", 1: "col2"}, inplace=True)

>>> df_result
   col1  col2
0     1    11
1     2    21
2     3    32
3     4    41
4     5    51
5     6    61
```

Comment: for some reason I get the following error when trying to build df_result: ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! Would you happen to know why?

Comment: I would say that `result_dict.items()` is for some reason wrong. Try to print it and check the result,

Comment: I put it in a list and it worked as such: df_result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(result_dict.items())). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird... `from_dict` means the source data would be a dict... Anyway, glad it worked